# Is it possible to draw a point interactively and execute an intersection operation (drill down) to identify spatial relationship with other layers?

Tags: intersection, boundless-suite

Is it possible to draw a point interactively and execute an intersection operation (drill down) to identify spatial relationship with other layers using GeoServer? I am a newbie with GeoServer…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: If by *draw interactively* you mean to be able to update your underlying data accessed through GeoServer the answer is **yes**. You have to be sure to enable the WFS-T protocol. Of course your DataStore has to be writable. Finally you need a WFS-T client, as GeoServer is just the middleware between a user interface and your database. The [Vector Layers](http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/vector/persist.html) section of the OpenGeo OpenLayers Workshop explains a easy way to do this. I recommend to you to do **both** the GeoServer and the OpenLayers workshop to settle your knowledge on those components.

Second: To do that geospatial analysis, even there is some effort to port the JTS library into JavaScript, I would recommend to use the GeoServer WPS capablities. It's advanced stuff, indeed. GeoServer has some built-in geoprocesses out of the box with the WPS plugin (not installed by default) and I think intersection is one of them. Check the [WPS plugin docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/index.html).

Comment: By draw interactively I mean to place the cursor in a specific location, mouse click and add a point where clicked. Is this the documentation you are referring to? http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/dataadmin/pgBasics/spatialrelationships.html

Comment: That docs are about PostGIS not GeoServer. Maybe you want to check also the [processing section](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/processing/index.html) of the OpenGeo suite docs.